# how to api key to google client in python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

How to pass api key to TextToSpeechClient client. I can't see in doc where to pass api key.
I can see only option to pass the json file path. Can i pass api key instead ?

```
    def list_voices():
        from google.cloud import texttospeech
        client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()
        voices = client.list_voices()
        for voice in voices.voices:
            print(f"Name: {voice.name}")
            for language_code in voice.language_codes:
                print(f"Supported language: {language_code}")
            ssml_gender = texttospeech.SsmlVoiceGender(voice.ssml_gender)
            print(f"SSML Voice Gender: {ssml_gender.name}")
            print(f"Natural Sample Rate Hertz: {voice.natural_sample_rate_hertz}\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use credentials, as API Keys are not supported. The credentials can be created from user OAuth or a service account. The easiest is to set up ADC (Application Default Credentials).

The CLI command to use during development:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

See this [link](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/libraries#authentication) for more details.